# Sass mixin that applies CSS hacks

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to create mixin that applies CSS hacks for different browsers:

```css
@mixin browsers($browsers) {
    $selectors: (
        chrome: '&:not(*:root)',
        firefox: '@-moz-document url-prefix()',
        ie: '@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none)'
    );

    @each $browser in $browsers {
        #{map-get($selectors, $browser)} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

```css
#test {
    @include browsers(firefox ie) {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Expected compilation output is:

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #test {
        background: red;
    }
}
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    #test {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

but it fails with:

```
Error: expected selector.

@-moz-document url-prefix(){
^
```

Of course I can use if/else statements inside @each like:

```css
@if $browser == chrome {
    &:not(*:root) {
        @content;
    }
} @else if $browser == firefox {
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        @content;
    }
} @else if $browser == ie {
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

but is it possible to do that more... elegant?

Comment: As far as I can tell you got what you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three and a half years, I've finally found a workaround and opened an issue in GitLab .

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/3636

```scss
@mixin only-ie {
  @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin only-chrome {
  &:not(*:root) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin only-firefox {
  @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin only-for-browsers($browsers) {
  @each $browser in $browsers {
    @if $browser == ie {
      @include only-ie {
        @content;
      }
    }

    @else if $browser == chrome {
      @include only-chrome {
        @content;
      }
    }

    @else if $browser == firefox {
      @include only-firefox {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Usage:
#test {
  @include only-for-browsers(ie firefox) {
    background: blue;
  }
  color: red;
}
```

## Update

It turned out to be much simpler, you just need to use `@#{}` instead of `#{}` in at-rules cases.

```scss
@mixin only-for-browsers($browsers) {
  $selectors: (
    chrome: '&:not(*:root)',
    firefox: '@-moz-document url-prefix()',
    ie: '@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none)'
  );

  @each $browser in $browsers {
    $selector: map-get($selectors, $browser);
    @if str-slice($selector, 1, 1) == "@" {
      @#{str-slice($selector, 2)} {
        @content;
      }
    } @else {
      #{$selector} {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }
}

#test {
  @include only-for-browsers(chrome firefox) {
    color: #e25922;
  }
  @include only-for-browsers(ie) {
    color: #1ebbee;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a comma.

```
#test {
    @include browsers(firefox ie) {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

should be

```
#test {
    @include browsers(firefox, ie) {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, `firefox ie` is parsing as `$browsers` argument value. As you can see `@mixin browsers($browsers)` gets just one argument, then parse it in `@each` part. Your code will return compilation error like "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)".